# HTT, 2.4.1.3, Lurie

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

Lurie claims the following is a formal consequence.

> [[2.4.1.3]](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf) Let $p:X \rightarrow S$ be an isomorphism of simplicials. Then every edge of $X$ is $p$-cartesian.

Definition of $p$-Cartesian is given at 2.4.1.1.

I would appreciate if someone can outline what is done to prove this. I am still very unfamiliar with the language of simplicial sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the notation in Lurie's. We have the isomorphisms in $Set_{\Delta}$, 
$$ X_{/y} \cong S_{/p(y)} \quad \quad   X_{/f} \cong S_{/p(f)} $$

And also the simple fact: for objects $a,b$ in a category, 
$a \times_a b \cong b$, where we take the pullback with respect to a morphism $b \rightarrow a$ and the identity $a \rightarrow a$.